# ReferenceError: process is not defined vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

```html
<script setup>
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const onChange = async () => {

  // Launch the browser
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

  // Create a page
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Go to your site
  await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com');

  // Evaluate JavaScript
  const three = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return 1 + 2;
  });

  console.log(three);

  // Close browser.
  await browser.close();


};
console.log(onChange);
</script>
```

here I am trying to scrape a website using (puppeteer) but I get an error

> in ReferenceError: process is not defined

Comment: you added a config?

Comment: no i dont add config? where to add

Comment: You already have a browser in the browser; why would you want another one?

Comment: @DaveNewton you cannot scrap easily with a browser AFAIK. I mean, automate that process besides clicking around haha.

Comment: read the official guide.

Answer (score 1):

From the [official page](https://pptr.dev/)

> Puppeteer is a Node.js library

You should probably not try to get that one working with VueJS (a client-side framework), gonna have a harder time for not a lot of benefits.

Use regular NodeJS for the scraping.

---

Otherwise, you could give a try to [Nuxt3](https://nuxt.com/) with its SSR capabilities if you think that having Puppeteer and Vue alongside is **crucial**.